# Decimal to time SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two decimals that are represented as time in SQL Server:

```
[Driver_Hours_QT]  
[Driver_Minutes_QT]
```

Result:

```
Driver_Hours_QT = 202.00000
Driver_Minutes_QT = 41.00000
```

I would like to concat these to get one time represented as 202.41 in order to divide by # of bills (394) to get a bill per hour.

How would I do this?

Comment: Presumably you mean divide the number of bills by the time period.

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Also I assume that 41 is minutes in which case 202 + 41 minutes is not 202.41 hours!!

Comment: Right, so it would be 202 hours and 41 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples, you want arithmetic:

```
Driver_Hours_QT + Driver_Minutes_QT / 100.0
```

Comment: When I add the two columns the result = 243.00000 when it should be 202.41

Comment: @DrewMurray . . . There is also a `/ 100` in the arithmetic.

Comment: `41` minutes != `0.41`!

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . I don't see your point.  Look at the result that the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

For bills per hour - you want to divide by the time

```
declare @hours as decimal
set @hours = 202
declare @mins as decimal
set @mins = 41

declare @bills as integer
set @bills =394

select @Bills/(@hours+@mins/60)
```

Obviously if you want Time per bill, then it's

```
select (@hours+@mins/60)/@Bills
```

Comment: So this would work for a single  example like I had listed above - but if I have multiple examples of  [Driver_Hours_QT] & [Driver_Minutes_QT] how would I write a blanket script that would work for multiple examples?

Comment: I used variables so that it was simple to test the statement, but you can interchange these with column names from a table or view and write the select the same way - obviously instead of @hours it would be the column name etc.

Comment: Say I have three examples:Say I have three examples: [Driver_Hours_QT]   ([Driver_Minutes_QT]   1.Driver hours = 202.00000 & Driver minutes=41.00000    2. Driver hours=145.00000 & Driver minutes=55.00000     3. Driver hours=286.00000 & Driver minutes=2.00000. How would this be performed considering setting @hours/@minutes would be different for each. I actually have 24 examples in total so the set would not work I do not think.

Comment: Huh? Where are you getting these "examples"? From a table?

Comment: Note the only bit of code I'd expect you to use is the last line - the select statement. Just replace the variables with column names.